# Highcharts single horizontal stacked bar chart with data names (labels) and %-ages always shown and data numbers and series name shown on mousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Is it possible to combine the following?

**[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/JEGGf/2/)** ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808135/highcharts-separate-categories)ed by [mäksä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230087/m%C3%A4ks%C3%A4)) **as a main template**:

- Single horizontal stacked bar with bar segments

**Combined with the following features of [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/potk4jpd/5/)** ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117712/semi-circle-donut-pie-chart-with-labels-data-names-and-ages-on-the-pie-a)ed by [aus_lacy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3922295/aus-lacy)):

Always visible on bar segments:

- Data names (labels) (i.c. "*`apples`*", "*`pears`*",...)
- Percentages (calculated if possible: "*`50%`*","*`50%`*",...)

Shown on mousehover:

- Original data numbers (i.c. "*`15`*","*`15`*",...)
- Series name/description (i.c. "*`Browser share`*")

---

**Almost but not quite:**

An example of a horizontal bar chart with "percentages" always shown, and "original data numbers" on mousehover can be found in **[Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/320/)** ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837209/highcharts-percentage-of-total-for-simple-bar-chart)ed by [jlbriggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011544/jlbriggs)), but there the "**data names**" are lacking, and I can't find a way to change the "**series name**". Further more: this is a horizontal bar chart, but this is not a **single stacked** one.

---

Any help would greatly be appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again it's a simple modification of the Highcharts attributes in particular this small snippet:

```
bar: {
        dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           distance : -50,
           formatter: function() {
                 var dlabel = this.series.name + '<br/>';
                 dlabel += Math.round(this.percentage*100)/100 + ' %';
                 return dlabel
           },
           style: {
                 color: 'white',
           },
        },

  },
```

I think [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/L0qsbfsb/) is what you are after?

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch for another precise answer.

Comment: And then (just a small adaptation to mimic the *Fiddle 1* lay-out) `gridLineWidth: 0`, can be added inside `yAxis: {`...`}`, to remove the vertical stripes/measure bars --- But after that, I am still wondering how to remove the **only remaining vertical stripe** (outmost left) which is also removed in *Fiddle 1*.

Comment: Works like a charm! I noticed your perfect solution was to add `lineWidth: 0,` inside `xAxis: {`...`}`.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother again, but I am still looking for some other details to completely mimic *Fiddle 1* some more. --- The legend can be removed by adding `enabled:false,` inside `legend: {`...`}`, the title can be removed by changing the text in `title: {`...`}` to `text: '',` the x-axis name can be removed by changing the text in `yAxis: {`...`}` to `text: '',`. --- But I haven't found out how to remove the **x-axis measure numbers** below the chart. Neither how to remove the **y-axis name** "*Fruits*", since this seems coupled with the series name on mousehover (which I want to keep).

Comment: Your precious help has allowed me to implement what I wanted. --- Unfortunately, a glitch is that for small bar segments, `dataLabels` will not be readable. --- I have posted a new question about it here: *[Highcharts single row stacked horizontal bar: labels overlap — bar segments too small to read “dataLabels” — (change “distance” of “dataLabels”?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126688/highcharts-single-row-stacked-horizontal-bar-labels-overlap-bar-segments-to)*, where you can also see the implementation I wanted to achieve.