# Highcharts single row stacked horizontal bar: labels overlap --- bar segments too small to read "dataLabels" --- (change "distance" of "dataLabels"?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

**Problem: overlapping and thus unreadable `dataLabels` in single row stacked horizontal bar.**

User [aus_lacy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3922295/aus-lacy) has kindly helped me to be able to implement the following code (especially in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124459/highcharts-single-horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-with-data-names-labels-and-ag/28125065#28125065)):

## HTML

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height: 300px"></div>
```

## JS (needs jQuery)

```
$(function(){$('#container').highcharts({chart:{backgroundColor:'gray',type: 'bar'},colors:['white'],credits:{enabled:false},title: {text:'Head and neck cancers (HNC)'},
xAxis:{categories:['Estimated 5-year prevalent cancer cases (×1000)'],lineWidth: 0,tickWidth:0,labels: {enabled:false,}},
yAxis:{min:0,title:{text:''},gridLineWidth:0,lineWidth:0,labels:{enabled:false,} }, legend: {enabled:false },
plotOptions: { series: { stacking: 'normal', borderColor: 'black' }, bar: { dataLabels: {enabled: true, distance : -50, formatter: function() { var dlabel = this.series.name + '<br>'; dlabel += Math.round(this.percentage.toFixed(1)*100)/100 + ' %'; return dlabel }, style: { color: 'black', }, }, }, },
series: [{ name: 'Oceania', data: [17]} , { name: 'Africa', data: [94]}, { name: 'Latin America and Carribean', data: [122]} , { name: 'Northern America', data: [181]}, { name: 'Europe', data: [383]},{ name: 'Asia', data: [886] } ] });});
```

His answer was completely perfect, but as now I want to use a new implementation, some bar segments got too small to reveal the text of the `dataLabels` (see the rendered `code` above).

---

## Perhaps ... or dead ends?

- The **`distance:-50,`** inside **`dataLabels:{`...`}`** (inside `plotOptions:{bar:{`...`}`) doesn't seem to work any longer.

I think if this **`distance`** were working, this might offer a solution, since if one e.g. adds `distance: 100,` inside `dataLabels:{`...`}` in the [standard pie chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/), one can clearly notice the difference. But a pie chart is obviously not a single row stacked horizontal bar?

- Perhaps another option would be to use the `useHTML`-option (see the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.useHTML) entry), although I can't figure out how to get things working.
- I think the easiest would be to have each next `dataLabel` slightly below the previous one? Could anyone achieve this? More or less brakes (`<br>`'s) inside certain `dataLabel`'s would create more possibilities, but I can not achieve this atm.
- ... something more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

**A fix I have found is to rotate the `dataLabels`.**

- Putting a rotation `rotation:-45` inside `dataLabels:{`...`}` and change `'<br>'` inside `formatter:function(){var dlabel=`…`}` to `': '` (to have single-line-labels. An additional brake (`<br>`) can be added before `Oceania` to improve readability (unfortunately I can't seem to be able to add more `<br>`'s).

Which gives the following code (copy the HTML from the question):

## JS (needs jQuery)

```
$(function(){$('#container').highcharts({chart:{backgroundColor:'gray',type: 'bar'},colors:['white'],credits:{enabled:false},title: {text:'Head and neck cancers (HNC)'},
xAxis:{categories:['Estimated 5-year prevalent cancer cases (×1000)'],lineWidth: 0,tickWidth:0,labels: {enabled:false,}},
yAxis:{min:0,title:{text:''},gridLineWidth:0,lineWidth:0,labels:{enabled:false,} }, legend: {enabled:false },
plotOptions: { series: { stacking: 'normal', borderColor: 'black' }, bar: { dataLabels: {enabled: true, distance : -50, rotation:-45, formatter: function() { var dlabel = this.series.name + ': '; dlabel += Math.round(this.percentage.toFixed(1)*100)/100 + ' %'; return dlabel }, style: { color: 'black', }, }, }, },
series: [{ name: '<br>Oceania', data: [17]} , { name: 'Africa', data: [94]}, { name: 'Latin America and Carribean', data: [122]} , { name: 'Northern America', data: [181]}, { name: 'Europe', data: [383]},{ name: 'Asia', data: [886] } ] });});
```

Unfortunately, for better results, the `width` might perhaps be enlarged in the HTML-code, which is to be avoided.

Further more: now we achieved a full line-spacing extra on one `dataLabel`, but it would be better to move this `Label` only 1/2 that distance, or only 1/3 of that distance; and move the surrounding `Label`('s) the same distance, away from the overlapping `Label`; for a more evenly spaced lay-out.